# Integrating Sphinx or other search engines with Question2Answer

Tags: sphinx, question2answer

My first impression from peeking into the source for Question2Answer is that it seems to be built to co-exist nicely with other OS applications. For example, one can plug in their own code for user database management or for localization - for example if one wanted to use gettext instead of PHP arrays for multilingual messages (even though it's just code filling in, not some OO pattern based  style - but that's a different matter all together).

However, there does not seem to be a pre design to allow plugging in search functionality. **My question is**: if anyone has integrated the sphinx search engine into Question2Answer, then what is the best technique or tips to achieve that.

I checked the docs on creating plugins here: http://www.question2answer.org/plugins.php, and the plugins system seems to accommodate certain types of functionality such as event handlers or content widgets - but not generic functionality or a  search module specifically.

Comment: Thanks - these were the tags I first tried, but didn't have the priv to add the [question2answer] tag. There needs to be a system where new users can at least 'propose' tags if they don't exist. Also: forcing a one tag on new users with no tag priv doesn't make sense as they can only choose a generic or irrelevant tag. I should raise these on Meta when/if I get time.

Comment: @Basel, the restriction on tag creation is precisely because newer users *do* tend to misunderstand and misuse the tag system.  We don't need and should not have a tag for every single software product or library under the sun.

Comment: The motivation behind the restriction is obvious. The issue raised is that imposing the 2 conditions simultaneously (!new_tag && 1_tag) can produce an irrelevant tag (and a comment about it for a bonus:)). Having a new user free not to tag seems unharmful (maybe). While at it, I'll suggest a Q&A generic tag for Q&A type software because I saw some questions mistakingly using qa (quality assurance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 1.5 of Question2Answer will support search modules in plugins which allow you to implement a custom indexer and search engine.